# Tomcat: How to point different directories to the same WEB-INF

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, subdomain, web-inf

Currently trying to setup multiple subdomains/domains in my Tomcat and I'm needing them all to use the same WEB-INF/classes/ for everything.

Basically my folder structure is like so:

```
Z:/
project/
    assets/   (assets.domain.com)
    main/     (www.domain.com)
    dev/      (dev.domain.com)
    WEB-INF/  (the WEB-INF I want everyone using.)
        classes/
            com/
                example/
```

So basically I need assets.domain.com, www.domain.com, and dev.domain.com to go up one level in the directory to find the WEB-INF and use the Java classes stored there... Is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to share java code across webapps, you will need to package them as jar and place it in either server/lib or endorsed folder . then each deployed webapp will have access to the same class files.

Comment: Seems like a pain in the butt when I'm in my development environment... Isn't there some easier way?

Comment: There is also `server/classes` where you can put class files. Not sure if it reloads properly during development, though.

Comment: Any way I can create a new Java project in Eclipse and have the bin/ changed to server/classes or turn it into a jar automatically and have it put into server/lib then?... I suppose that could work, decently...

Comment: webapps are explicitly forbidden to share class files in servlet spec. You may have to look at upgrading to ear packaging to do it in a standard way - look at tomEE however, this may be an overkill for a task like this. Another way will be to create a custom classloader for your apps -little effort and pain in butt required :)

Comment: Seems like a lot of pain and hardship for a few subdomains. :\

Comment: Got the build path set to lib/ in my Tomcat 7 installation folder. Seems to be working with that set and making Eclipse not clean the output folder before building. Thanks for the tips! Not exactly ideal but... Hey, it works.

Comment: @Tynarus use `Maven` for a cleaner setup